# Ошибка KeyError: 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код

```
while True:
    #logins=input("Введите номер телефона")
    #password2=input("Введите пороль")
    #appid=input("Ввведите  id созданного вами приложения")
    try:
        api=vk_requests.create_api(app_id=app,login=l2 ,password=f45)
        break;
    except:
        #print("Введенные вами данные не верны");
        #logins=input("Введите номер телефона")
        #password2=input("Введите пороль")
        #appid=input("Ввведите  id созданного вами приложения")
print("success");

while True:    
    global s2
    def infoname():

        print(" ")
        print(s2);
        ln=s2[0]['last_name']
        print(ln);

    def infoi():
        try:
            i=input();
            s2=api.users.search(q=(i),count=2);
            global s2
        except:
            print("err");
        else:
            infoname();

    infoi();
```

При работе с массивом возникает ошибка

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\c#\vkp\vkp\vkp.py", line 40, in <module>
    infoi();
  File "F:\c#\vkp\vkp\vkp.py", line 38, in infoi
    infoname();
  File "F:\c#\vkp\vkp\vkp.py", line 27, in infoname
    ln=s2[0]['last_name']
KeyError: 0
```

Мне нужно из массива взять `last_tname`, `first_name`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать ?

Модуль `Vk-request python 3.5`

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что в словаре `s2` нет ключа `0`. Покажите что в `s2` находится.

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря s2 нужно взять значение (список) по ключу `'items'`, а из этого списка  уже выбрать нулевой элемент:

```
ln=s2['items'][0]['last_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо написать:

```
ln=s2['items']['last_name']
```

Comment: `s2['items'][0]['last_name']`